# Use Telerik converter service through WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I'm trying to visit the webpage http://converter.telerik.com/ using a `WebBrowser` control in a WinForms application but the page contains script errors.

After `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` to **True** the main controls of the webpage are unable to load at this point i'm lost about using the `WebBrowser` control to this task so I've search other alternatives.

I've tried with the latest build of `GeckoFX` (29.0.X) from here: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/

With the `GeckoWebBrowser` control the Telerik page loads perfectly but after pressing the "**Convert**" button from my `GeckoWebBrowser` the second "Textbox" gets crazy and is not properly displayed, so again I'm lost but I don't know what more alternatives I have.

In the past i've tried to use some builds of chrome for .Net but I was unable to compile them.

What I need to do to use the Telerik converter service using any kind of webbrowser from my app?

PS: Dependencies are not a problem for me, I just want to develop a personal application for my only usage to load/save snippets that I converted using the Telerik service accessing to its converter webpage from my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would take a look at SharpDevelop's NRefactory Library and see if I could utilize this in my application instead of using someone else's webservice which more than likely uses NRefactory as it's underlying engine.

The online version of the code converter is available at http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/.

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Code-Converter
https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/NRefactory

About NRefactory:

- ICSharpCode.NRefactory is freely available as a part of SharpDevelop IDE.
- It is parser library for C# and VB.
- It consists of a single Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) that can represent all constructs that are available in C# or VB (unlike System.CodeDom, which only represents constructs common to C# and VB).
- By using the C# parser and a VB output visitor (or vice versa), you can do a code converter.
- After parsing to AST, you can analyze and/or transform the AST and re-create source code from the (modified) AST, then re-insert the comments we saved from the parser into the output
- For more info about NRefactory please see: sharpdevelop.net and NRefactory wiki.
- You may try samples\NRefactoryDemo in the SharpDevelop source code to take a look how the AST parse source code.

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262950/CodeConverter

Comment: I have many offline free and paid .Net converters but my experience says that Telerik offers the best converter service with the highest percentage of a good translation without errors, but unafortunately the service is provided online then I need to use it online. I'm not looking for software/service alternatives, my question was clear. Thanks for your help, +1, sorry for my English.

Comment: forget my last comment, I didn't noticed that Telerik's converter uses NRefactory! I tried to translate some codes with "critical" syntax that other converters always fails and both Telerik's and Sharpdevelop online converter translated the code exactly equals, its really good, I'm reading your linked urls to know if or how I can implement this in my app, thanks so much

Comment: Yes, can be seen here telerik uses NRefactory from SharpDevelop: http://converter.telerik.com/about.aspx. You should be able to add reference to the library and utilize it in your own application :)

Comment: thanks, I just want to note something, from your last link (source) I have all the paid/free mentioned converters that uses NRefactory such as Tangible vb.net<>C#, convert.NET, NetVert, etc and only Telerik online service can convert properly some snippets. If all those products are using the same technique contained in the NRefactory dll then why some of them fails with specific codes?, well anyays I will try it for myself the expectatives of this conversion in my own app.

Comment: And to finalize my comments I ant to say that I also resolved the way of using Telerik's service through a web browser, I needed to use EO WebBrowser, is an amazing paid control for .Net with full js support, I didn't have any problem with it to load the Telerik webpage.